# Change orientation layout manager for inner recyclerView in MergeAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to change orientation layout manager to horizontal for inner recyclerView in [MergeAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter),
is it possible to add adapters in order to show them in horizontal as [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/312fN.png) in [MergeAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter)?

Comment: Did you solve this?